# If one layout (main) have only one orientation, should all the others also have only one orientation?

Tags: screen-orientation

Aplication (game) has 3 activitys with different layouts.

1. The menu layout where user can choose to play the game or see the score.
2. The score layout.
3. The game layout.

If I decide that the game layout should only have one orientation (landscape orientation), should I make all the other layouts also one orientation only?

If the user starts in portrait orientation, press the play button and then have to turn the device around to landscape mode will that annoy the user? Is it better to force the user to use the whole app in landscape orientation from the start to achive better user expperience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's a case of "annoying" the user, it's more a case of - why wouldn't you do this?

If the whole gaming experience is landscape, then what is the rationale for starting in portrait?

Even if only for consistency, I would keep the whole experience landscape.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to force landscape mode for play, I wouldn't see a need to develop portrait mode purely for score and menu layouts (I'm assuming on pause or on endgame).

I'd caution you, however, to consider whether your game is playable as both horizontal and vertical orientations, or if, due to game design constraints, it's only possible to play it in horizontal mode.  Because of the multitude of different user preferences and screen sizes, different users may wish to play the game in either mode.  Forcing horizontal view could needlessly alienate a segment of your target audience.  Additionally, there may be strategic value in different situations of one mode over another.  If it at all possible, I'd give my users a choice about screen orientation.

I realize these considerations have to be made against a backdrop of information I don't have access to, such as design and development capability, budget, time frame, gameplay, limited QA resources.  I'm sure you'd consider each before making an ultimate decision.